# Windows Phone 10 with Office365 Business account - can't upload camera pics

Tags: windows-10-mobile, onedrive, camera, office-365

I have an Office 365 E3 account and a brand new Windows 10 phone (Lumia 930). Reset the phone to factory settings, reinstalled and added the O365 account. It does appear in OneDrive and I can view the contents. However, I can not enable the camera upload - the slider is greyed out in the off-position. From that screen I can go into account settings and see my O365 account.

Is there some kind of black magic required to upload my camera's pictures to the O365 Onedrive?

Comment: I know [historically that Onedrive for business didn't support camera roll](https://community.office365.com/en-us/f/173/p/263696/806263#806263) - not sure if this has changed as the [clients have converged](https://blogs.office.com/2015/12/16/onedrive-for-business-update-on-storage-plans-and-next-generation-sync-client/)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, Rowland. Starting with this tread I have searched and found that one (https://community.office365.com/en-us/f/154/p/425351/1069080?ss=30ad82b4-2e2e-4347-ac96-cceaed7ee67b#1069080) dating to January 2016. While it only applies to IOS, I assume that it's valid for WP 10, too. So bad. What worries me, too, is that even when I have BOTH a personal and the business OneDrive configured, it won't let me enable the camera roll (to store the pics in the personal OneDrive). Such a shame, Microsoft... Please tell me I'm entirely wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opened an incident with Microsoft and got this nice and friendly reply:

> Wie Sie auch selber gesehen haben, funktioniert diese Option nur mit privaten OneDrive Konten. Das momentan ist eine Einschränkung der mobilen Betriebssystem. Sie könnten Ihre Meinung dafür unter der folgenden Webseite äußern: https://office365.uservoice.com

translated

> As you have noticed yourself, this option is only available with private OneDrive accounts. This is currently a limitation of the mobile operating system. You can give your optionion to this on the following website: https://office365.uservoice.com

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution that is free, uses Microsoft components and no third party components or plugins. It's a process to configure your Office 365 account to reach into your OneDrive and copy the files over. Full steps and screenshots are here

http://www.v-wiki.net/copy-photos-onedrive-business/

Comment: Please post the relevant part of the solution here. Link-only answers can become useless if the link ever changes or becomes unavailable. For more information, see [How do I write a good answer?](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)